# MySQL encryption library similar to SQLCipher

Tags: mysql, database, security, encryption, sqlcipher

I'm working on encrypting some database fields. By encrypting of course I lose some search functionality. I found this library called [SQLCipher](http://www.zetetic.net/code/sqlcipher) which handles the encryption at the database level, but it's for SQLite. Is there something similar for MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its not free :

http://solutions.mysql.com/solutions/item.php?id=834

Comment: "Page not found" ... would you mind sharing the name of the "solution"? Thanks!

Comment: wooooow !  its was a long time ago, sorry i do not remember

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at [zNcrypt for MySQL](http://www.gazzang.com/products/ezncrypt-for-databases.html)? Could be useful to you.